# posting data on jquery post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Using jquery

```
$.post('target.php', data, function(result) {
  window.open('target.php');
});
```

In target.php

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

Results in

> array(0) { }

I have the code above inside ajax success after success I want to open the target page in new tab and sending data in that page.

But this results in an empty array.

How to correctly send data using post request and how to retrieve it in target page

Comment: If your `localhost/target.php` url is working fine then you can directly `window.open('correct_url')` without making a post Ajax call. And if you still wants a extra call to your page so check network tab of developer tool your request is going correctly and what response you are getting, your url is correct of not .

Comment: what does data contain?

Comment: @Manwal but how can i send data using post if i directly do `window.open('correct_url')` actually this is how i do right now i send data using the url and getting using get but that data are showing and i dont like it so i turn to using POST this time.

Comment: @Manwal is there a way to send data by directly calling `window.open('correct_url')` at the same time sending POST data?

Comment: No a window.open will open URL in new tab that will make GET call instead of POST. You need to debug your file why you are not getting data correctly.

Comment: @Manwal yes that is what i am doing now. I dont like it people will see the data i need to make it in a way that people will not see so i need to use POST.. is there a way?

Comment: @AgamBanga it is a json type data where i put all the information i need in target.php

Comment: i have added an answer. let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do like below

```
var data = {suggest: 'Any String'};
$.post("target.php", data, function(result){
   window.location.href = 'target.php'
});
```

In PHP Side, You can store that in `$_SESSION` variable like this

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    $_SESSION['my_post_data'] = $_POST;
    echo 'done';
    exit;
}
```

When the page is opened using `window.open` method, you can get the POST data using

```
print_r($_SESSION['my_post_data']);
```

Comment: still getting blank when doing var dump for $_POST

Comment: can you print `file_get_contents('php://input')` in your php file

Comment: it prints blank

Answer (score 0):

jQuery post is an ajax call that happens on the background and therefore you won't be able to achieve it that way.
What you can do is a normal form post to the new tab.

```
<form target="_blank" action="target.php" method="post"> ... </form>
```

Notice the target blank like in a link. Then submit that form.

```
$('form').submit()
```

Comment: this is not the solution am looking for

Comment: This is the only way to post to a new tab